# Getting from Kuching to Semenggoh

Tags: public-transport, transportation, malaysia

Many guidebooks (including Lonely Planet *Borneo* Aug 2019 edition) and websites still claim that you can take Bus No. 6 (4 ringgit) from Kuching to Semenggoh.

However, my hostel staff tell me that that bus went out of service maybe 2 years ago. (Indeed, someone updated the [Kuching Wikitravel](https://wikitravel.org/en/Kuching) page, stating "**Attention: As of December 2018, there is no bus No. K6 at 13.00 anymore!!!**")

They tell me the only ways to get there now are by taxi/Grab/tour arrangement, which seem to cost something like 90 ringgit for the return trip.

Are there any other cheaper ways to get from Kuching to Semenggoh?

Answer (score 1):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Kuching/Semenggoh-Nature-Reserve) also agrees - taxi is looking like your only option, unless you hitch, perhaps?

Consider seeing if others at the hostel also want to join in on a trip, and it may help cut down the costs.  Or see if your hostel staff will drive you - for say, half the price of a taxi, maybe, if you can barter it down.